# Function, mutable borrow

Tags: rust, ownership

I am trying to understand the ownership system. To test it, I wanted to make a function that borrows a `Vec`, adds a value to it and returns that value:

```
fn test(v1: &mut Vec<i32>) -> i32 {    
    *v1.push(10);    
    v1[3]
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<i32> = vec![10, 20, 30];
    let i: <i32> = test(&mut vec);
}
```

I get these two errors:

```
error: expected `::`, found `=`
 --> src/main.rs:8:16
  |
8 |   let i: <i32> = test(&mut vec);
  |                ^

error: type `()` cannot be dereferenced
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     *v1.push(10);    
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Changing the `=` to `::` doesn't help and I don't understand why it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not wrap all types with `<>`. `<>` means that you want to specify a generic parameter. This is sufficient:

```
let i: i32 = /* value */;
```

What is more, you do not need to specify the type at all, the compiler will infer types on it's own. You can just write:

```
let mut vec = vec![10, 20, 30];

let i = test(&mut vec);
```

This should solve your second problem.

The first error is because you are trying to dereference `()`, which isn't a reference at all.

In C (and C++) we have 2 different access operators:

- `.` which allows you to access structure fields (and methods in C++)
- `->` which allows you to access fields of a structure behind a pointer

Rust hides these details from you, so you only need to use the `.` operator.

The type of `Vec::<T>::push(&mut vec, val: T)` means that it returns `()` (the unit type). To fix the problem, remove the `*`:

```
fn test(v1: &mut Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    v1.push(10);

    v1[3]
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![10, 20, 30];
    let i = test(&mut vec);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works now. I thought that I would need the * to acces the contents of the reference.

Comment: Dereferencing first, while unnecessary, should still work: you just have to use brackets so it will be parsed as `(*v1).push(10)` and not `*(v1.push(10))`. This is the same operator precedence as in C.